# How to reset all ReactiveVars to false in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template where recipes are rendering through {{#each recipes}} and I'm using ReactiveVar to toggle the edit form of each recipe from hide to show. Everything works fine, but I want that when I press edit button in one recipe then all other recipe forms, which were opened before, will set to hide

```
Template.Recipe.onCreated(function(){
        this.editMode = new ReactiveVar(false);
    });

Template.Recipe.helpers({
    editMode: function() {
        return Template.instance().editMode.get();
    }
});

Template.Recipe.events({
    'click .fa-pencil': function(event, template) {
        //Right here I guess should be something that switches all "editMode" to false
        template.editMode.set(!template.editMode.get());
    },
});
```

Comment: "(...) but when I toggle one instance, I want it to hide the others"?

Comment: I meant that when I press the edit button in one place and a form slides down in this place, then all other forms slide up and hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a different approach

a Session variable which has the Id of the current editing recipe and then helper on the template to see if the current recipe is the one being edited

add a property to the recipe whether its being edited or not, then update the collection when you change which one is edited

A common object with a reactive var, and much the same technique as the Session variable.  If you have a parent template, then it could live there  (this is probably the nicest option)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this functionality, you should think about how your templates communicate. One template shouldn't be able to set the state for it's siblings, which means you are thinking it wrong.

You should store that state somewhere global so all templates can see and react to it. That option would mean using Session (as Keith mentioned) or a route parameter (better option, in my opinion).

Another option is to use the parent to store that data, using events to communicate between parent and children. A child template can send and event to the parent who direct another event to each other child.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there is some easy way to do this, but not.

Comment: I'd argue that using routes to save application state is about as easy as using plain local reactive vars. :p